# Gallery stops working after 2nd use

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So i have a weird problem in a site im building.
In the "about" page, theres a small gallery showing some pictures.
The first time you enter the page, everything works as intended.
Now, Lets say i exit the "about" page and go to any other page in the website, the moment ill re enter the "about" page again, it will stop working.
It will work again once i refresh the page, and the problem continues again.

this is how the gallery is built:

HTML:

```
<div class='about_slide_show' id="about_slide_show">
    <div class="gc_next_arrow">
        <div class="arrow_block">
            <img src="./images/arrow_right.png" alt="" id="au_next" onclick="pic_next(3)">
        </div>          
    </div>
    <div class="gc_prev_arrow">
        <div class="arrow_block">
            <img src="./images/arrow_left.png" alt="" id="au_prev" onclick="pic_prev(1)">
        </div>              
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.about_slide_show{
    width: 50%;
    min-width: 650px;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #cacaca;
    background-image: url('./images/about/2.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.gc_next_arrow{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    right: 0;
}
.gc_prev_arrow{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 0;
}

.arrow_block{
    color: #000;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 120px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
var ext_numbers,
    pic_files,
    max_value;
    $(document).ready(function(){       
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                if(xmlhttp.responseText){
                    xml_data = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    xml_data1 = xml_data.split("/");
                    ext_numbers = xml_data1['1'].split("+");
                    pic_files = xml_data1['0'].split("+");
                    max_value = Number(pic_files['0']);
                    document.getElementById("about_slide_show").style.backgroundImage = "url('./images/about/"+pic_files['2']+"')";
                }
                else{

                }
            }                                               
            else{

            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("POST",'check_about.php',false);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send();
    });
    function pic_next(nid){
        if(Number(nid) <= max_value){
            $("#about_slide_show").fadeOut(50,function(){
                document.getElementById("about_slide_show").style.backgroundImage = "url('./images/about/"+pic_files[Number(nid)]+"')";
                $("#about_slide_show").fadeIn(250,function(){
                    document.getElementById("au_prev").onclick = function(){pic_prev(ext_numbers[Number(nid) - 1]);};
                    document.getElementById("au_next").onclick = function(){pic_next(ext_numbers[Number(nid) + 1]);};
                });
            });
        }
    }
    function pic_prev(pid){
        if(pid > 1){
            $("#about_slide_show").fadeOut(50,function(){
                document.getElementById("about_slide_show").style.backgroundImage = "url('./images/about/"+pic_files[Number(pid)]+"')";
                $("#about_slide_show").fadeIn(250,function(){
                    document.getElementById("au_prev").onclick = function(){pic_prev(ext_numbers[Number(pid) - 1]);};
                    document.getElementById("au_next").onclick = function(){pic_next(ext_numbers[Number(pid) + 1]);};
                });
            });
        }
        else if(pid == 1){
            $("#about_slide_show").fadeOut(50,function(){
                document.getElementById("about_slide_show").style.backgroundImage = "url('./images/about/"+pic_files[Number(pid)]+"')";
                $("#about_slide_show").fadeIn(250,function(){
                    document.getElementById("au_prev").onclick = function(){};
                    document.getElementById("au_next").onclick = function(){pic_next(ext_numbers[Number(pid) + 1]);};
                });
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $folder_path = "./images/about/";
    $files = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir($folder_path));
    $sort_flags = 1;
    sort($files,$sort_flags);   
    echo count($files);
    foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
        echo '+'.$value;
    }
    echo '/null';
    foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
        $temp_files = explode(".", $value);
        echo "+".$temp_files['0'];      
    }
?>
```

The AJAX call inside the `$(document).ready` function simply gets a string which contains the number of pictures in the about folder, the picture file names, and their names without extension.
the string the AJAX call returns look something like this:

2+1.jpg+2.jpg/null+1+2

Then i just break the string and insert it into arrays.

The JavaScript after is just for navigating through the gallery (next pic and previous).

Could anyone have an idea why im having this issue?
I'll provide any extra info if necessary.

Thanks.

Comment: the result of the ajax call you pasted: 2+1.jpg+2.jpg/null+1+2  - is from a working run? If it is, something must not be right nevertheless with this "null" being returned... if it is not from a working run - then the problem might be related to this

Comment: the null is something i added simply so the first array key will be 1 and it will contain the first image. for example file_names['1'] will have 1.jpg in it. instead of having file_names['0'] containing 1.jpg.

Comment: I can't run your code, but based on your description of the problem, it must be something related to the code inside $(document).ready(). Since it works fine only in the first execution. If you navigate to another page, and re-enter the "about" one - have you checked if the script with the $(document).ready is being loaded and executed ?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, seems like removing the `$(document).ready` function solved it.

so instead of:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            if(xmlhttp.responseText){
                xml_data = xmlhttp.responseText;
                xml_data1 = xml_data.split("/");
                ext_numbers = xml_data1['1'].split("+");
                pic_files = xml_data1['0'].split("+");
                max_value = Number(pic_files['0']);
                document.getElementById("about_slide_show").style.backgroundImage = "url('./images/about/"+pic_files['2']+"')";
            }
            else{

            }
        }                                               
        else{

        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST",'check_about.php',false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send();
});
```

i used this:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
        if(xmlhttp.responseText){
            xml_data = xmlhttp.responseText;
            xml_data1 = xml_data.split("/");
            ext_numbers = xml_data1['1'].split("+");
            pic_files = xml_data1['0'].split("+");
            max_value = Number(pic_files['0']);
            document.getElementById("about_slide_show").style.backgroundImage = "url('./images/about/"+pic_files['2']+"')";
        }
        else{

        }
    }                                               
    else{

    }
};
xmlhttp.open("POST",'check_about.php',false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send();
```

I figured the HTML was loading after the AJAX call and all the variables werent set yet.